# React Native returns [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed] when I'm making a Post Request

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, axios, http-post

When I make a post request in React Native with Axios it returns a [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed].
This is my json and my axios method

```
const credentials= {
NickName: "ricardo.luna",
Password: "123",
AccesoAplicacion: 1,
DerechosRangoInicial: 1000,
DerechosRangoFinal: 1012
}

const loginAxios = () => {
axios
  .post('x.x.x.x/API/users', credentials)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.IdUser);
  });
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your post params as [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();

bodyFormData.set('NickName', 'Fred');
bodyFormData.set('Password', '123');
bodyFormData.set('AccesoAplicacion', 1);
bodyFormData.set('DerechosRangoInicial', 1000);
bodyFormData.set('DerechosRangoFinal', 1012);

const loginAxios = () => {
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'x.x.x.x/API/users',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Or you can use [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) module to build your query string

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const credentials= {
NickName: "ricardo.luna",
Password: "123",
AccesoAplicacion: 1,
DerechosRangoInicial: 1000,
DerechosRangoFinal: 1012
}

const loginAxios = () => {
axios
  .post('x.x.x.x/API/users', querystring.stringify(credentials))
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.IdUser);
  });
 };
```

Comment: thanks, I used the fist structure but instead of using the FormData I used my credentials object and ran smootlhy

Comment: @RicardoLuna glad to help you, And also please don't forget to give a vote up also 

Comment: Thanks I did, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :( It's actually the first question a do here

Answer (score 0):

just add after the .then() `.catch(error=>{})` to handle the rejection and catch the error returned